# Como fazer uma chamada de um arquivo que contem um formulário com ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Como eu chamo um arquivo que tem o conteudo do formulário das condições?

Html

```
<label>SELECIONE UMA OPÇÃO</label>
     <form>
      <label><input value="A" name="opcao" type="radio">opcao A</label> 
      <label><input value="B" name="opcao" type="radio">opcao B</label>
      <label><input value="C" name="opcao2" type="radio">opcao C</label> 
      <label><input value="D" name="opcao2" type="radio">opcao D</label> 
      <div>
                CONTEUDO DO FORMULARIO AQUI
      </div>

     </form>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(event) {
                        var option1 = $('input[name="opcao"]').filter(':checked').val();
                        var option2 = $('input[name="opcao2"]').filter(':checked').val();
                        getForm(option1, option2)

                    });

                    // Traz o form com ajax
                    function getForm(option1, option2){
                        console.log(option1);
                        console.log(option2);

                        if ( (option1 == 'A') && (option2 == 'C') ) {
                            // Faz uma chamada ajax para trazer o formulario
                        }

                        if ( (option1 === 'A' && option2 === 'D') ) {
                            // Faz uma chamada ajax para trazer o formulario
                        }

                        if ( (option1 === 'B' && option2 === 'C') ) {
                            // Faz uma chamada ajax para trazer o formulario
                        }

                        if ( (option1 === 'B' && option2 === 'D') ) {
                            // Faz uma chamada ajax para trazer o formulario
                        }
                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar várias `<div>`s com diferentes formulários e exibir só os que você quer dentro do seu `script`. Por exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<div id='form1'></div>
<div id='form2'></div>
<div id='form3'></div>
```

**Script**

```
if ( (option1 == 'A') && (option2 == 'C') ) {
    // Faz uma chamada ajax para trazer o formulario
    $('#form1').show();
}    
if ( (option1 === 'A' && option2 === 'D') ) {
    // Faz uma chamada ajax para trazer o formulario
    $('#form2').show();
}
```

Comment: Assim eu sei chamar queria chamar um arquivo tipo.

<?php require_once('/config.php'); ?>

Comment: O que exatamente voce quer retornar de acordo com cada condicao? Um formulario especifico pra cada opcao, ou um arquivo de configuracoes p/cada? seja mais especifico...